# Create a space between two buttons in my banner

Tags: html, css

How to do a space of 0.5 cm between 2 buttons in my banner ? I am stuck since several moment. Should I to change my blocks en HTML ? 
[image]

Here in my code in CSS

```
.myButtonRegister{
  float: left;
  background-color: #C22312;
  color: white;
  height: 48px;
  width: 168px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white; 
  font-family: 'Pridi', serif;
  font-size: 26px;
  padding-top: 10px; 
  word-spacing: 0px;
}
.myButtonRegister a {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.myButtonLogin{
  float: left;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  height: 48px;
  width: 168px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white; 
  font-family: 'Pridi', serif;
  font-size: 26px;
  padding-top: 10px; 
  word-spacing: 0px;
}
.button-action {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

Do you have an idea ? 
Thanks for your answer.
Regards

Comment: can you please show us html code as well, since we don't know what css class connects with which html element

Comment: Did you try `.myButtonRegister { margin-right: .5cm }` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add margin-right: 30px; attribute to your class myButtonRegister.

```
.myButtonRegister{
 float: left;
 background-color: #C22312;
 color: white;
 height: 48px;
 width: 168px;
 text-align: center;
 color: white; 
 font-family: 'Pridi', serif;
font-size: 26px;
 padding-top: 10px; 
word-spacing: 0px;
margin-right: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add below line in class **myButtonRegister**

```
 margin-right:10px;
```

You can change 10px as per your need.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting in `.myButtonRegister` class this rule `margin-right: 50px;`